# Stop scrolling at the top of slider when click link href target id pure css

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a pure css slider here but the problem is I dont want to scroll at the top of the slider when click the bullet and arrow navigation from the extra space.

Is there any way to achieve this with pure html or css?

I tried `a href="#s3/"` and `a href="#s3!"` but it's not working.

Looking for pure html and css solution since we have no script cms. Thanks

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow:scroll;
height:700px;
}

/* For visual purpose only */
.extra-space {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
   line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
 
}

/*slider*/

.CSSgal {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Or set a fixed height */
}


/* SLIDER */

.CSSgal .slider {
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 0.8s;
}


/* SLIDES */

.CSSgal .slider>* {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: none 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* PREV/NEXT, CONTAINERS & ANCHORS */

.CSSgal .prevNext {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.CSSgal .prevNext>div+div {
  visibility: hidden;
  /* Hide all but first P/N container */
}

.CSSgal .prevNext a {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.CSSgal .prevNext .right {
  right: 30px;
  left: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 92.2%, .6) !important;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none !important;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.CSSgal .prevNext .left {
  left: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: none !important;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 92.2%, .6) !important;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.CSSgal .prevNext .left:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(https://new.brandsforless.ae/static/media/m-sprite.7b312d28.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: -76.5px -7px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.CSSgal .prevNext .right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(https://new.brandsforless.ae/static/media/m-sprite.7b312d28.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: -49px -7.5px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.CSSgal .prevNext a:hover {
  background-color: #ebebeb!important;
}

.CSSgal .prevNext a+a {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}


/* NAVIGATION */

.CSSgal .bullets {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.CSSgal .bullets>a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #f8d000;
  border: 2px solid #f8d000;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.CSSgal .bullets a span {
  display: none;
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.left {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.CSSgal .bullets>a+a {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: 2px solid #999;
  /* Dim all but first */
}

.CSSgal .bullets>a:hover {
  background: #f8d000;
  border: 2px solid #f8d000;
}


/* NAVIGATION BUTTONS */


/* ALL: */

.CSSgal>s:target~.bullets>* {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: 2px solid #999;
}


/* ACTIVE */

#s1:target~.bullets>*:nth-child(1) {
  background: #f8d000;
  border: 2px solid #f8d000;
}

#s2:target~.bullets>*:nth-child(2) {
  background: #f8d000;
  border: 2px solid #f8d000;
}

#s3:target~.bullets>*:nth-child(3) {
  background: #f8d000;
  border: 2px solid #f8d000;
}


/* More slides? Add here more rules */


/* PREV/NEXT CONTAINERS VISIBILITY */


/* ALL: */

.CSSgal>s:target~.prevNext>* {
  visibility: hidden;
}


/* ACTIVE: */

#s1:target~.prevNext>*:nth-child(1) {
  visibility: visible;
}

#s2:target~.prevNext>*:nth-child(2) {
  visibility: visible;
}

#s3:target~.prevNext>*:nth-child(3) {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* More slides? Add here more rules */


/* SLIDER ANIMATION POSITIONS */

#s1:target~.slider {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
}

#s2:target~.slider {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}

#s3:target~.slider {
  transform: translateX(-200%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="extra-space">
  <h1>Extra space</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="mb-4">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 p-0">
          <div class="CSSgal">

            <!-- Don't wrap targets in parent -->
            <s id="s1"></s>
            <s id="s2"></s>
            <s id="s3"></s>

            <div class="slider">
              <div>
                <a href="/en-ae/brands/troop-london/">
                  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="prevNext">
              <div>
                <a class="left" href="#s3"></a>
                <a class="right" href="#s2"></a>
              </div>
              <div>
                <a class="left" href="#s1"></a>
                <a class="right" href="#s3"></a>
              </div>
              <div>
                <a class="left" href="#s2"></a>
                <a class="right" href="#s1"></a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bullets">
              <a href="#s1"><span>1</span></a>
              <a href="#s2"><span>2</span></a>
              <a href="#s3"><span>3</span></a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i manage to fix this by add `s{display: none;}` which hiding the id.

```css
/*** the solution ***/
s{
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow:scroll;
height:700px;
}

/* For visual purpose only */
.extra-space {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
   line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
 
}

/*slider*/

.CSSgal {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Or set a fixed height */
}


/* SLIDER */

.CSSgal .slider {
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 0.8s;
}


/* SLIDES */

.CSSgal .slider>* {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: none 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* PREV/NEXT, CONTAINERS & ANCHORS */

.CSSgal .prevNext {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.CSSgal .prevNext>div+div {
  visibility: hidden;
  /* Hide all but first P/N container */
}

.CSSgal .prevNext a {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.CSSgal .prevNext .right {
  right: 30px;
  left: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 92.2%, .6) !important;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none !important;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.CSSgal .prevNext .left {
  left: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: none !important;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 92.2%, .6) !important;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.CSSgal .prevNext .left:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(https://new.brandsforless.ae/static/media/m-sprite.7b312d28.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: -76.5px -7px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.CSSgal .prevNext .right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(https://new.brandsforless.ae/static/media/m-sprite.7b312d28.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: -49px -7.5px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.CSSgal .prevNext a:hover {
  background-color: #ebebeb!important;
}

.CSSgal .prevNext a+a {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}


/* NAVIGATION */

.CSSgal .bullets {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.CSSgal .bullets>a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #f8d000;
  border: 2px solid #f8d000;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.CSSgal .bullets a span {
  display: none;
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.left {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.CSSgal .bullets>a+a {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: 2px solid #999;
  /* Dim all but first */
}

.CSSgal .bullets>a:hover {
  background: #f8d000;
  border: 2px solid #f8d000;
}


/* NAVIGATION BUTTONS */


/* ALL: */

.CSSgal>s:target~.bullets>* {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: 2px solid #999;
}


/* ACTIVE */

#s1:target~.bullets>*:nth-child(1) {
  background: #f8d000;
  border: 2px solid #f8d000;
}

#s2:target~.bullets>*:nth-child(2) {
  background: #f8d000;
  border: 2px solid #f8d000;
}

#s3:target~.bullets>*:nth-child(3) {
  background: #f8d000;
  border: 2px solid #f8d000;
}


/* More slides? Add here more rules */


/* PREV/NEXT CONTAINERS VISIBILITY */


/* ALL: */

.CSSgal>s:target~.prevNext>* {
  visibility: hidden;
}


/* ACTIVE: */

#s1:target~.prevNext>*:nth-child(1) {
  visibility: visible;
}

#s2:target~.prevNext>*:nth-child(2) {
  visibility: visible;
}

#s3:target~.prevNext>*:nth-child(3) {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* More slides? Add here more rules */


/* SLIDER ANIMATION POSITIONS */

#s1:target~.slider {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
}

#s2:target~.slider {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}

#s3:target~.slider {
  transform: translateX(-200%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="extra-space">
  <h1>Extra space</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="mb-4">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 p-0">
          <div class="CSSgal">

            <!-- Don't wrap targets in parent -->
            <s id="s1"></s>
            <s id="s2"></s>
            <s id="s3"></s>

            <div class="slider">
              <div>
                <a href="/en-ae/brands/troop-london/">
                  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="prevNext">
              <div>
                <a class="left" href="#s3"></a>
                <a class="right" href="#s2"></a>
              </div>
              <div>
                <a class="left" href="#s1"></a>
                <a class="right" href="#s3"></a>
              </div>
              <div>
                <a class="left" href="#s2"></a>
                <a class="right" href="#s1"></a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bullets">
              <a href="#s1"><span>1</span></a>
              <a href="#s2"><span>2</span></a>
              <a href="#s3"><span>3</span></a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```